# Rate limiting inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have multiple services running inside a kubernetes cluster and all talking to each other. I want one of the services to have a rate limiting feature. This means that for certain caller ids it should accept only 50 calls per minute and reject all others with 429 "Too many requests". This limiting should happen for calls inside the same cluster.

Can this be done using k8 objects/features?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Circuit Breaker in [istio](https://istio.io/) (kubernetes addon), which can be achieved by creating traffic policy connection pools with istio `destinationrule` objects.

According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#circuit-breakers):

> #### Circuit breakers
>
> Circuit breakers are another useful mechanism Istio provides for creating resilient microservice-based applications. In a circuit breaker, you set limits for calls to individual hosts within a service, such as the number of concurrent connections or how many times calls to this host have failed. Once that limit has been reached the circuit breaker “trips” and stops further connections to that host. Using a circuit breaker pattern enables fast failure rather than clients trying to connect to an overloaded or failing host.
>
> As circuit breaking applies to “real” mesh destinations in a load balancing pool, you configure circuit breaker thresholds in  [destination rules](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#destination-rules), with the settings applying to each individual host in the service. The following example limits the number of concurrent connections for the  `reviews`  service workloads of the v1 subset to 100:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
> kind: DestinationRule
> metadata:
>   name: reviews
> spec:
>   host: reviews
>   subsets:
>   - name: v1
>     labels:
>       version: v1
>     trafficPolicy:
>       connectionPool:
>         tcp:
>           maxConnections: 100
> ```
>
> You can find out more about creating circuit breakers in  [Circuit Breaking](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/circuit-breaking/).